# invalid syntax in python code, when running on Linux (Windows is ok)

Tags: python, linux

I'm running a python code having this fragment:

```
logger.info("Done building vocab from corpus.")

return {word: (i, freq) for i, (word, freq) in enumerate(vocab.iteritems())}
```

I keep getting this message on Linux, although on a Windows machine it runs. I copied the files to the Linux server using WinSCP. I could really use some help.

```
return {word: (i, freq) for i, (word, freq) in enumerate(vocab.iteritems())}
                          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My distribution:

```
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Release:        6.6
Codename:       Final
```

Comment: 99% chance: the CentOS machine is running an old version of Python that doesn't support dictionary comprehensions. What version of Python is it running?

Comment: Looks like CentOS only comes with 2.6 at most, so there you go (dictionary comprehensions were added in 2.7).

Comment: ok, thanks @TigerhawkT3
I will upgrade and reort

Comment: That is it. Working after upgrading to Python2.7. thanks for that !